# Swift Pass in Properties on Older iOS versions

Tags: ios, swift

As an example say I have the following code that takes in a string and a UITextContentType.

```
var items: [Item] = [
    TextField.init(
        title: "First Name", 
        textContentType: UITextContentType.givenName
    ),
]
```

But my application targets versions before iOS 10 where UITextContentType was implemented. What is the best way to deal with this?

Xcode fix-it wants me to `@available` to the enclosing var or class. But that would mean that on previous versions my application would crash.

Also here is my code where I set textContentType.

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    textField.textContentType = textContentType
}
```

So basically I want to say if it's not on iOS pass nothing in, or nil or something along those lines.

How can I achieve this while still writing code that doesn't repeat a ton and in the cleanest way possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually just able to solve this by changing the code to the following.

```
var items: [Item] = [
    TextField.init(title: "First Name", textContentType: {() in 
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) { 
            return UITextContentType.givenName 
        } else { 
            return nil 
        } 
    }()),
]
```

If anyone else has ideas of how to make this code cleaner and shorter that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

In place of nil you can use :

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    return UITextContentType.givenName
} else {
    return UITextContentType(rawValue: "")
}
```

Comment: What would be the benefits to this vs nil?